# PHP Startup: zmq: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, ubuntu, zeromq

I'musing PHP 5.5.13 via Bitnami Lamp Server in Ubuntu
ZM extension is not loading.
in th error log I got this message:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zmq: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20090626\nPHP    compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.5 uses a newer compiler version under Windows. You have to use VC11 Modules and not VC 9 modules.

Under Linux its the same. Its a new compiler version. Install the module over PECL if its in the repo or install it over the package manager. To compile the module you can use `phpize`. Then its compiled with the correct compiler version and you can use it.

http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq

http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Linux iv'e mentioned it in my question